# Case-insensitive string comparison without using lower or upper

Tags: python, string, compare, case-insensitive

I am trying to compare two string and ignore case- sensitive but i don't want to use .lower() or .upper(). Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: The big question is... why?

Comment: It seems to me to be unreasonable to do lower twice so i'd wanted to know if there is another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
example1 = "hello"
example2 = "HeLlo"

if example1.casefold()==example2.casefold():
    #do something
```

This will work without needing `upper()` or `lower()`. Might not work for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: This might give different invalid results - `"ß".casefold() == "ss"`

Comment: @Sayse Yes this is assuming ASCII. Does `.lower()` and `.upper()` work well for non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @Sayse that seems like a valid result?